# Newbie: Multiple WP sites on Windwos 2012 IIS

Tags: iis, windows

Newbie Question:

I have a Windows 2012 server with an existing ASP.NET / HTTPS site on it running a small SQL Server as well. My customer wants to add a dozen or so WordPress sites, one for each of its States. They must be independent with separate logins, separate sites etc, but the backend data store can be the same if need be.

Is this possible without damaging the existing ASP.NET site? I've been reading on it, but it seems that I could damage the site installing WP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you look at Wordpress Multisites? It should run if your current site is already running on ASP

http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

https://premium.wpmudev.org/